# How to wrap a container div around a Ckeditor table onOk

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When a user enters a table on the Ckeditor, I want to wrap a div around it with a class but I can't find a way to get this table HTML element. What is the best way to go about it?

I've tried creating a plugin to extend the table dialog onOk function (see code). This gives me all the properties from the table dialog but I don't want to have to create the whole table element again with all the properties as I don't want to re-write the existing table plugin.

I just need to get the code this plugin adds and wrap it in a div.

I thought about doing it in my projects javascript, when page loads, get all tables and wrap it in a div.  However, this doesn't seem like the best way to do it at all.  I thought there must be a way via ckeditor?

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'responsivetables', {
    // The plugin initialization logic
    init: function(editor) {
        vsAddResponsiveTables(editor);
    }
});

function vsAddResponsiveTables(editor){
    CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

        if ( dialogName == 'table') {
           addTableHandler(dialogDefinition, editor);
        }
    });
}

function addTableHandler(dialogDefinition, editor){
    dialogDefinition.onOk = function (a) {
        // get table element and wrap in div? 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer so for anyone else that needs it, this is what I did:
I used the insertElement event instead of when dialog was closed, only doing what I need if its a table that's being added.

```
// Register the plugin within the editor.
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'responsivetables', {
    // The plugin initialization logic goes inside this method.
    init: function(editor) {
        vsAddResponsiveTables(editor);
    }
});

function vsAddResponsiveTables(editor){ 
    // React to the insertElement event.
    editor.on('insertElement', function(event) {
        if (event.data.getName() != 'table') {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new div element to use as a wrapper.
        var div = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div').addClass('table-scroll');

        // Append the original element to the new wrapper.
        event.data.appendTo(div);

        // Replace the original element with the wrapper.
        event.data = div;
    }, null, null, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To the previous answer by 'gemmalouise' need to add one more line of code

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.extraPlugins = 'responsivetables';
}
```

Otherwise it will not work (I cannot indicate this in the comment, because lack of 50 reputation).
And more compact code of this fuctional:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('responsivetables', {
    init: function (editor) {
        editor.on('insertElement', function (event) {
            if (event.data.getName() === 'table') {
                var div = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div').addClass('table-scroll'); // Create a new div element to use as a wrapper.
                div.append(event.data); // Append the original element to the new wrapper.
                event.data = div; // Replace the original element with the wrapper.
            }
        }, null, null, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Also don't forget about buffer passed - you can handle like this:

`(function () {
    function wrapTable(data) {
        var val = data.replace('<table', '<div class="large-content"><table');
        val = val.replace("</table>", "</table></div>");
        return val;
    }

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('responsivetables', {
        init: function (editor) { 
            editor.on('insertHtml', function (event) {
                event.data.dataValue = wrapTable(event.data.dataValue);
            }, null, null, 1);
        }
    });
})();`